# Does a screenreader pause on SPANs

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers

If for presentational purposes one needs to separate a word with `span`s or other inline elements, does a screenreader still read the whole word?

Example:

```
<code>span</code>s
```

or

```
Forscher<span class="gendered">In</span>
```

Comment: which screenreader  are you using?

Comment: sorry, if I was using one I wouldn't need to ask that question. I'm happy to know about any one. (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally screen readers don't pause in this case. However, if a user enables font changes and/or colors reporting, it might cause interruptions like this:

> Consolas span Arial s

for `<span>`s. That's because the code segments are rendered with Consolas font here at StackOverflow, and normal text is in Arial.

Comment: Thank you. It's quite surprising that font or color changes are being read out. Which Screenreader is that?

Comment: In this particular test it was JAWS, however this is common functionality. And please note: this *doesn't happen* by default. I mean, most users would hear "spans" and not "Consolas span Arial S". I've pointed out that for this a screen reader's settings should be modified.