# How are inline-tags extracted by search engines or screen readers?

Tags: html, search-engine, screen-readers

Let's take this as an example, where the heading is in normal font weight, but the two digits and the last part of the logo are written in bold:

```
<h1>20<span>14</span> Stack<span>overflow</span> takes over</h1>
```

How is this read by search engines and screenreaders? Does it result in:

> 2014 Stacokoverflow takes over

or:

> 20 14 Stack overflow takes over

Woud it be necessary to add the whole text in the `title`-attribute?

```
<h1 title="2014 Stacokoverflow takes over">[…]</h1>
```

Comment: [Recent related question about screen readers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25115589/1591669)

Comment: @unor Wow, that's some strange issue. Basically the same question only two days earlier. I've flagged mine as a duplicate. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Screen readers with default settings will read the full number 2014. However, a user may enable font changes announcement, and in this case he/she would hear "20 bold 14".
As for title, there's no great sense to do this since (again, by default) titles are ignored if there is some text between the opening and closing tags.

Comment: Interesting points. So all semantically irrelevant elements are removed and whitespaces are kept (or in this case not added)? Can it be broken down to this? Interesting is also the "font changes" feature. Does it only anounce changes for the style (like bold or italic) or also uppercase, size and underlines?

Comment: Yes, you can think so. As for fonts announcement, this is very flexibly tweakable (at least, in JAWS for Windows, but other screen readers also provide these settings). You may, for example, set it to announce only size changes, only bold announcement, etc., etc. Generally this is not used due to the tremendously increased chattiness. the only use case I know is proofreading/web design.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insights. *Generally this is not used due to the tremendously increased chattiness.* - that's what I figured.